# In general, do linear models have unexplainable error or error that isn't shown in the data?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I'm running linear regression on a model and performed backward selection on it. Then in order to check for the fit of the model, I did cross validation on it.

The linear model:

```
 GoalWeight ~ Measurement + Age + Gender
```

With backward selection:

```
 GoalWeight ~ Measurement + Gender
```

When I cross validated both models, I found little movement in the points. In order to check what was happening, I found the mean squares and the variable importance with the varImp function.

```
 cvTotal <- CVlm(form.lm = formula(GoalWeight ~ Measurement + Gender + Age), data = clean_GW2, m = 3)
 cvBS <- CVlm(form.lm = formula(GoalWeight ~ Measurement + Gender), data = clean_GW2, m = 3)

 attr(cvTotal, "ms")
 attr(cvBS, "ms")
```

The MS (kind of unsurprisingly) was the same for both models.

```
 varImp(linmod, scale = TRUE)
 varImp(new_linmod, scale = TRUE)
```

When I performed the varImp function, the output was

```
> varImp(linmod, scale = TRUE)
                  Overall
clean_GW2$Measurement    60.7
clean_GW2$Gender         30.9
clean_GW2$Age             1.0
> varImp(new_linmod, scale = TRUE)
                  Overall
clean_GW2$Measurement    60.9
clean_GW2$Gender         31.0
```

I do notice that the overall importance of the variables does not equal 100%. Is the remaining ~10% error that is unexplainable by the model?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation from `?varImp`, for linear models it returns "the absolute value of the t–statistic for each model parameter is used," so those numbers are scalars indicative of statistical significance, not percentages.

This can be seen below:

```
library(caret)
a <- rnorm(1000,1,2)
b <- rnorm(1000,-2,1)
c <- rnorm(1000,1.5,3)
d <- rnorm(1000)
e <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000,0,2)+a+b+c+d
df <- data.frame(y=y,a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d,e=e)
mod <- lm(y~.,df)
varImp(mod)
    Overall
a 30.9973810
b 14.1027980
c 43.4574054
d 15.3868891
e  0.1844951

sum(varImp(mod))
[1] 104.129 #not a percentage
```

All models that aren't perfect (so basically all models) have unexplained variation, but for a linear model this is related to your r-squared value and not the output of `varImp`